# Прикрепить дочернее окно к родительскому winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

Каким образом при запуске дочернего окна его можно прикрепить к родительскому и далее при перемещении родительского, перемещалось дочернее?

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду [Многодокументный интерфейс](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81)?

Comment: @АндрейNOP не совсем. Мне нужно просто закрепить дочернее окно на родительском в статичном состоянии. Перемещение осуществляется только вместе с родительским окном.

Answer (score 1):

Вот Решение

```
/// <summary>
/// Класс отвечат за событие перемешения окна
/// </summary>
public static class WindowMoveClass
{
    private static Point WindoPoint;

    public delegate void WindowPosChanged();

    public static event WindowPosChanged OnWindowPosChanged;

    public static Point Point
    {
        get { return WindoPoint; }
        set {
            if (value != WindoPoint)
            {
                WindoPoint = value;
                if (OnWindowPosChanged != null)
                {
                    OnWindowPosChanged();
                }

            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Родительское окно (Form1)

```
private void Form1_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WindowMoveClass.Point = this.Location;
        }
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form3 asd = new Form3();
            asd.Show();
        }
```

Дочерние окно

```
 public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        WindowMoveClass.OnWindowPosChanged += ChangeLocation;
    }

    void ChangeLocation()
    {
        this.Location = WindowMoveClass.Point;
    }
```